# Saving to renamed user folder

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-folders

(This happened with a remote coworker)

He did the following (on Windows 10):

1. Renamed `C:\Users\OriginalName` to `C:\Users\DifferentName`
2. Moved (not copied) his files into the Documents folder (by clicking on `Documents` in the left bar in File Manager)
3. Later named `C:\Users\DifferentName` back to `C:\Users\OriginalName`

We tried changing username values in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` and (in an Administrator account) `Computer Management(Local) -> Local Users and Groups`.

We tried all four username permutations but still can't access his files. Is there a way to retrieve them?

Comment: The process used to rename the user profile directory was incorrect.  The best and only method I know that works is to use the prompt that is displayed after unlinking a Microsoft Account.  An Administrator will have to move the files for the user

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean by the prompt? He is using a local account only.

Comment: Yes;  If you were to link that account to a Microsoft Account;  Then immediately unlink the Microsoft Account, there is a  prompt, and asks for the profile name.  You can change the user directory and username, instantly.  **The method your friend used has never worked.**

Comment: @Ramhound I know it doesn't work for renaming, now he doesn't want that, just wants to get his files back.

Comment: Can they use the built-in Administrator to assign the proper permissions?

Comment: @Ramhound the problem is we don't know what permissions are needed